# Reloading Multiple images

Tags: texturing, image

I am working on a visualisation project where I am constantly tweaking around 20 textures at the same time, Is there a way to quickly reload all of the textures?

I am aware of "save-reopen" method (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *>* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and *Reload Image* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) but both of them are rather dirty and time consuming.

Is there a way to refresh and reload all of the textures at once?

Answer (score 11):

This refreshes all the UV textures I have assigned to different objects:

```
import bpy

for image in bpy.data.images:
    image.reload()
```

Paste this into the Text Editor view, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to execute it, and all your textures will be refreshed.

Comment: Thank you, so simple yet so useful!

Answer (score 4):

You can also:

1. Change the textures.
2. *Save* the file.
3. Then use *File*> *Revert*. It will revert the file to the last saved version and reload all textures at once.

**BEWARE!** You must always save the file before doing the revert!

Comment: The problem with this method is that it erases all Undo History, making workflow more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

1. File > External Data > Find Missing File.

[image]